# Google Maps for opengts

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, gprs

We are implementing opengts product on large scale, so wanted to know, if it is better to go with normal google maps provided apps or should we integrate with google enterprise.

What can be the cost of google enterprise and how can we apply for it.

Comment: Have you investigated API usage limits (either volume or throughput)?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you need a "Google Maps API for Business" license, here is a quote from Terms of Service for free Google Maps APIs:

> 10.2 Restrictions on the Types of Applications that You are Permitted to Build with the Maps API(s). Except as explicitly permitted in Section 8 (Licenses from Google to You) or the Maps APIs Documentation, **you must not** (nor may you permit anyone else to) do any of the following:
>
> > (c) No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise Applications. You must not use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of the following:
> >
> > > (iii) **enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking or similar applications**. If you want to engage in enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking, or similar applications, please contact the Google Maps API for Business sales team to obtain a Google enterprise license. (If you are offering a non-enterprise implementation, you may use the Google Maps API(s) to track assets such as cars, buses or other vehicles, as long as your tracking application is made available to the public without charge. For example, you may offer a free, public Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public transit or other transportation status information.)